# Touchscreen with KVM switch gives clicks

Tags: kvm-virtualization, touchscreen

Im currently running a shuttle pc with the latest version of Ubuntu with a ELO touchscreen connected via a KVM switch (Belkin SOHO with usb hub).

On the other machine (a custom os) it works fine, instand connection and no random clicks. But in Ubuntu it takes a few seconds after you switch the kvm for the touchscreen to be found and when the KVM is not active the cursor gives random pulses every few seconds/minutes.

I've installed the original ELO touch drivers and the screen is calibrated.

What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by the KVM switch you used.  The KVM switch does not support touch screen sharing which requires keep connecting the touch screen no matter it was switched off to other PC/systems.

You can find a "DDM class" KVM switch which will keep the connection of sharing devices (specially for the HID devices - keyboard, mouse and touch screen monitor...etc) even when you switch between/ among connected systems.

The DDM class KVM switches will not cause any delay after you switching between/among connected systems.